# Returning a variable from a function containing a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a app that uses steamapi from npm and I need to get a variable from a function which contains a promise to render a html page to a client.

here is the code I have so far.

```
const SteamAPI = require('steamapi');
const steam = new SteamAPI('redacted');

function steampicture(steamid) {
    steam.getUserSummary(steamid).then(function (data) {
        return summary.avatar.large;
    })
}

function steamname(steamid) {
    steam.getUserSummary(steamid).then(summary => {
        return summary.nickname;
    })
}


var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var steamid = req.query.steamid;
    console.log(steampicture(steamid))
    res.render('index.html', {
        name: steamname(steamid),
        picture: steampicture(steamid),
    });
});



app.listen(80);
```

thanks, IOnicisere

Comment: Can you be precise, which variable, which function?

Answer (score 0):

`steampicture` and `steamname` are asynchronous. You need to return the promises they generate so you can render the response *after* they have performed their async calls.

Something like:

```
function steampicture(steamid) {
  // return the promise
  return steam.getUserSummary(steamid).then(function (data) {
      return data.avatar.large;
  })
}

function steamname(steamid) {
  return steam.getUserSummary(steamid).then(summary => {
      return summary.nickname;
  })
}
```

Since you need to wait for both to resolve, you can call them and save the retuned promises in an array which you can pass to [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

`Promise.all` will resolve when both promises have resolved. *Then* you can render the result. Something like:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var steamid = req.query.steamid;
  let promises = [
    steamname(steamid),
    steampicture(steamid)
  ]
  Promsie.all(promises)
  .then(([name, picture]) =>{
    res.render('index.html', {name, picture})
  });
  })
```

You can (and probably should) refactor this to call `steam.getUserSummary()` once and return the avatar and nickname from the same call. This would simplify everything a lot.

Something like:

```
function steampicture(steamid) {
  return steam.getUserSummary(steamid).then(data =>  {
      return [data.avatar.large, data.nickname]
  })
}
```

would allow you to make one async call and avoid the `Promise.all`.

Answer (score -1):

You should return the variable wrapped inside another Promise. You can't be sure that your function will succeed, so you should probably handle the failure too

Comment: im not particularly good at javascript. how exactly would i do this?